# Cannot connect to SQL Server Compact Database from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to connect to an existing `*.sdf` file from my solution using [these leads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322(v=vs.140).aspx) but Add Connection dialog box doesn't open, so I try to connect manually: go to "Data sources", click "Add new" and choose Microsoft SQL Database File, but while choosing db file at first filter doesn't allow me to choose my `*.sdf` file. When I set filter to "All files" and select my file, I get exception: "Failed to determine the version of database file".
So what can I do to connect to this database?

Comment: The connection to `Microsoft SQL Server Database File` is a connection to a full-fledged SQL Server `.mdf` file - not a SQL Server Compact `.sdf` file ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1) is the most usefull tool for SQL Compact. I hope, it  solve all your problems.